# Allocating a price to a service in SQL Server hotel reservation

Tags: sql-server

I have a customer table and services table in SQL Server 2012. A customer can avail services if he wants, laundry, housekeeping, food.

In `Customer` table I have kept services as a multivalued attribute. When I resolve it, I make an associative entity for services table where I put C_id*, Service and Price.

My question is what query to write a subquery at time of table generation in of customer to enter a particular price for a service availed? Basically how to handle this? I would later use these to create an invoice when total bill calculated.

Likewise, I have member types as well. If a member is lifetime then allow 20 percent discount and seasonal 10 percent.

How to handle it? Subqueries?

Code snippets would help.

Comment: What do you mean with "in Customer table i have kept services as a multivalued attribute". Are you storing data separate with comma or something like that?

Comment: yes if customer avails more than one service

Comment: First thing you need to do is stop doing that. You need to store one thing in one column, no comma separated lists.

Comment: yes created an assoicative entity by name of services for that.

Comment: Any help as in how to set prices for these services in the subquery?

Comment: can you provide proper table schema of your customer table.

as i understood your query, i will suggest you to use 3 tables for handling all this . 1- customer(which will only have customer details like Name,Id,IsLifeTimeMember)
2- service(service will have services details like name ans price)
3- serviceUsed (which will have customerId,serviceId)